# Trying to extend partition

Tags: rhel, disk

I have a Hyper-V RHEL VM where root has run out of space. In Hyper-V, I reallotted 1TB of disk space to the VM (it was about 120 GB before).

In RHEL, I have this:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel-root   51G   38G   14G  74% /
```

I did `lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/rhel_rhel-root`
which returned

```
Size of logical volume rhel_rhel/root unchanged from <50.25 GiB (12863 extents).
  Logical volume rhel_rhel/root successfully resized.
```

I've never run out of space before so I don't really know what I'm doing. Why did lvextend not work?

Comment: Your logical volume is part of a volume group, which likely does not have any available storage on it. Run `vgs` to see output detailing information about the volume group. If the volume group is out of space, you can add more to it using `vgextend`, which can allocate additional physical volumes to the volume group. My guess is that your volume group has not been extended to include the 1TB of disk space you added.

Comment: Let me make sure I have my logic correct before I go screwing things up. I use fdisk to create a new partition. Then I use pvcreate to create a new physical volume. Then I can do vgextend, lvextend, and xfs_growfs. Does that sound right?

Comment: You don't need to create a new partition: you can just expand the one that's already there. What does `fdisk -l` look like right now?

Comment: `Disk /dev/sda: 1073.7 GB, 1073741824000 bytes, 2097152000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c6b9c   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   262143999   130022400   8e  Linux LVM`

Comment: I did `pvresize /dev/sda2` which says it resized the volume, but when I run `pvs`, it says ` PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree

  /dev/sda2  rhel_rhel lvm2 a--  <124.00g    0`

Comment: It seems like I need to do [this](https://networklessons.com/uncategorized/extend-lvm-partition). Is that not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research and experimentation, I found the solution here: https://networklessons.com/uncategorized/extend-lvm-partition

There was one difference for my server. Since I have XFS instead of Ext4, for the last command I replaced `resize2fs` with `xfs_growfs /root`.